# How to show this equation equals zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $P(z)$ denote a complex polynomial of degree $n$ with simple zeros $a_1, . . . , a_n$. Show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_k^p}{P'(a_k)}=0$, for $p=0,1,...n-2$.

I have no idea where to start and the naive way of solving it by brute force is just not working. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${\bf Hint}$: We see that $\frac{a_k^p}{P'(a_k)}$ is the residue of $f(z) = \frac{z^p}{P(z)}$ at the simple pole $z=a_k$. By the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) the sum can therefore be rewritten as a contour integral

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k^p}{P'(a_k)} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{z^p}{P(z)}{\rm d}z$$

where $\gamma$ is any contour enclosing all of the roots $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ of $P(z)$. Take $\gamma$ to be a circle of radius $R$ and estimate the integral using the [estimation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) in the limit $R\to \infty$.

---

The result can also be derived using only the tools from real analysis. Here is a proof sketch. One first [show that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences#Expanded_form)

$$f[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n] = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f(a_k)}{P'(a_k)}$$

where $f[a_1\ldots,a_n]$ is the [divided difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences) of $f$. Next the [mean value theorem for divided differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem_%28divided_differences%29) says that 
$$f[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n] = \frac{f^{(n-1)}(\zeta)}{(n-1)!}$$

for some $\zeta\in[\min(\{a_k\}_{k=1}^n),\max(\{a_k\}_{k=1}^n)]$. Taking $f(z) = z^p$ with $p\leq n-2$ then this implies $f[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n] = 0$ and the result follows.