# Proving Polynomial Identities

Tags: polynomials

I have proved that for an order $n\leq 5$ (I haven't checked past this order) monic polynomial $p(\lambda)$ whose roots have multiplicity 1, the following identities are true

$$\sum_i\frac{\lambda_i^k}{p'(\lambda_i)}=0,\quad 0\leq k\leq n-2$$
$$\sum_i\frac{\lambda_i^{n-1}}{p'(\lambda_i)}=1$$
$$\sum_i\frac{\lambda_i^n}{p'(\lambda_i)}=\sum_i\lambda_i$$

Where $\lambda_i$ are the roots of $p(\lambda)$ and $p'(\lambda)$ is the derivative of $p(\lambda)$. I proved this by using Vieta's formulas for the coefficients of the polynomial in terms of the $\lambda_i$'s, and explicitly evaluated. I'd like to prove this is true for any order polynomial, any ideas?

Comment: You have to assume that the roots are single, as otherwise it may happen that $p'(\lambda_i)=0.$

Comment: That's a great point, I will add that to the post.

Comment: There must be some normalization: the leading coefficient equal $1,$ as multiplying the polynomial by a constant will influence the last two formulas.

Comment: Ah, I neglected to specify my normalization, I will fix that.

Comment: I am pretty sure that your identities follow from the Vandermonde matrix and its determinant. For example the product of the denominators is the Vandermonde determinant of the roots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving a formula for $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j^k}{f'(x_j)}$ for $f$ an $n$-th degree polynomial with $n$ distinct real roots $x_j$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4074098/proving-a-formula-for-sum-j-1n-fracx-jkfx-j-for-f-an-n-th-degr). Also see [How to show this equation equals zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545215/how-to-show-this-equation-equals-zero) and [Prove $\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{a^s_r}{f'(a_r)} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168658/prove-sum-r-1n-fracas-rfa-r-0).

Comment: Yes this answers my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use decomposition into simple elements.

Let $A = a_0 + \cdots + a_mX^m$ and $B = b_0 + \cdots + b_nX^n$ be two polynomials in $K[X]$ with degrees $m$ and $n$. Assume that $B$ has $n$ distinct (hence single) roots $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Then
$$\frac{A}{B} = Q + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{c_i}{X-\lambda_i}$$
where $Q$ is the quotient of $A$ by $B$ in the Euclidian division (with degree $(m-n)_+$ and $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ are constants in $K$.

Evaluation of $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ is simple in this case: let $B_i$ be the polynomial such that $B=(X-\lambda_i)B_i$. Then $B'=B_i+(X-\lambda_i)B_i$. Evaluating at $\lambda_i$ yields $B'(\lambda_i) = B_i(\lambda_i)$. But we have also
$$\frac{A}{B_i} = (X-\lambda_i)Q + (X-\lambda_i)\sum_{j \ne i} \frac{c_i}{X-\lambda_i} + c_i$$
Evaluating at $\lambda_i$ yields
$$\frac{A(\lambda_i)}{B'(\lambda_i)} = \frac{A(\lambda_i)}{B_i(\lambda_i)} = c_i.$$
As a result,
$$\frac{A}{B} = Q + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{A(\lambda_i)}{B'(\lambda_i)} \frac{1}{X-\lambda_i}.$$
Multiplying by $X$ and using
$$\frac{X}{X-\lambda_i} = 1 + \frac{\lambda}{X-\lambda_i}$$
yields
$$\frac{XA}{B} = XQ + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{A(\lambda_i)}{B'(\lambda_i)} + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{Q(\lambda_i)}{P'(\lambda_i)} \frac{\lambda_i}{X-\lambda_i}.$$
We recognize the decomposition of the fraction $(XA)/B$ into simple elements. Hence the quotient of $XA$ by $B$ in the Euclidian division is $$XQ + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{A(\lambda_i)}{B'(\lambda_i)}.$$
This quotient has degree $(m-1-n)_+$.

If $m \le n-2$, this quotient is $0$, like $Q$, so
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{A(\lambda_i)}{B'(\lambda_i)} = 0.$$

If $m \le n-1$, this quotient is $a_m/b_n$ whereas $Q=0$, so
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{A(\lambda_i)}{B'(\lambda_i)} = \frac{a_m}{b_n}.$$

When $A=X^n$ and $b_n=1$, this quotient is $X - b_{n-1}$ whereas $Q=1$, so
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{A(\lambda_i)}{B'(\lambda_i)} = - b_{n-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i.$$